# Content Editable CPT Archive?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I have a CPT called `foobar` the archive of the CPT defaults to `example.com/foobar/` I have my cpt set to use an archive, because I want the user to see content when visiting `example.com/foobar/` - I want to be able to edit this content, much like any other page in the backend .

However this requires the `archive_foobar.php` - and as we all know, archive pages in backend are not editable. You see where I'm going here I'm sure.

I've been a WP developer for years, searched long and hard and have not yet come across a solution to this that isn't convoluted with ACF fields, extra plugins, redirects and so forth.

my closest thoughts of a workaround would be to create a page in the CPT called perhaps `Homepage`, and set a custom `wp_query` in `archive_foobar.php` to pull in that page content... but this seems hacky/creates duplicate content (As `example.com/foobar/homepage` will exist as well.)

It seems their may not be an elegant solution currently with WordPress, and if so it seems like quite an oversight?

Has anyone had any luck with creating a workflow for this?

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm setting `'has_archive' => false` in the CPT and creating a page with the same permalink as the post type's slug (foobar) - and re-saving permalinks. The query for the listing can be done in `page-foobar.php` or inside the page builder (shortcode or a CPT listing block).

Looks less hacky to me but can have some SEO consequences I guess.

*Further thoughts:
Something simulating the setting page as "Posts page" in Reading options which would work with CPTs should be the wp-friendly way.*